# Calculate two sums from a column that has two classes

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, dom

From a table, I need to sum the value from one of the column.
but they will have either A or B as their class.
I want both sum of A and sum of B.

Class/Value

A / 3

B / 2

B / 7

A / 1

==> A sum : 4 / B sum : 9

Also when I remove a row, sum should be changed as well.
(Not sure it would automatically re-sum when I remove it from other code)

I was considering putting if-else condition inside for loop to separate the classes, but couldn't figure out well.

Comment: share your code

Comment: Can you provide some code pls what you've tried so far?

Comment: Is this a normal html table that has Class and Value as headers?

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` after converting `querySelectorAll` into an array:

```js
let A = [...document.querySelectorAll("table .A")].reduce((acc, curr) => acc + +curr.innerText, 0);
let B = [...document.querySelectorAll("table .B")].reduce((acc, curr) => acc + +curr.innerText, 0);
console.log(A);
console.log(B);
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <td class="A">3</td>
  <td class="B">2</td>
  <td class="B">7</td>
  <td class="A">1</td>
</table>
```